# Drag and Drop in Vaadin with save order

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a problem in Vaadin7.

I want to create a drag and drop between Task and List (Task dragable, List dropable).

My code is working but task is always dropped on the very bottom of the list.

This is my code (drop handler):

```
@Override
public AcceptCriterion getAcceptCriterion() {
    return AcceptAll.get();
}

@Override
public void drop(DragAndDropEvent event) {
    DragAndDropWrapper dd = (DragAndDropWrapper)event.getTransferable().getSourceComponent();
    Task t= (Task) dd.getData();
    DragAndDropWrapper dd2 = (DragAndDropWrapper)event.getTargetDetails().getTarget();
    List targetList = (List)dd2.getData();
    String currentDraggedTaskId = t.getTask_id();
    final int targetListId = Integer.parseInt( targetList.getId_list() );
    try {
        taskService.moveTask(currentDraggedTaskId, targetListId);
        List targetListObj = (List)CollectionUtils.find(allLists, new Predicate() {
            @Override
            public boolean evaluate(Object object) {
                List l = (List)(object);
                return l.getId_list().equals(targetListId+"");
            }
        });
        List oldList = (List)t.getParent().getParent();
        oldList.removeComponent(t.getParent());
        targetListObj.addComponent(t.getParent());

    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException | SQLException e) {
        Notification.show("err");
    }

}
```

I know that I'm adding the task to the end of layout, but how can I know where on the list, the Task was dropped?

I will be very grateful is someone could help me :)

Best regards, 
Matt.

Answer (score 0):

There is more/different information about the drop-location, depending on the type of Component receiving the drop. This is from the Book Of Vaadin (see [here](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.dragndrop.html)):

> The TargetDetails object provides information about the exact location
>   where the transferable object is being dropped. The exact class of the
>   details object depends on the drop target and you need to cast it to
>   the proper subclass to get more detailed information. **If the target is
>   selection component, essentially a tree or a table, the
>   AbstractSelectTargetDetails object tells the item on which the drop is
>   being made.** For trees, the TreeTargetDetails gives some more details.
>   For wrapped components, the information is provided in a
>   WrapperDropDetails object. In addition to the target item or
>   component, the details objects provide a drop location. For selection
>   components, the location can be obtained with the getDropLocation()
>   and for wrapped components with verticalDropLocation() and
>   horizontalDropLocation(). The locations are specified as either
>   VerticalDropLocation or HorizontalDropLocation objects. The drop
>   location objects specify whether the transferable is being dropped
>   above, below, or directly on (at the middle of) a component or item.

So it may be a solution to use a Table instead of a List.